# How to deploy: Mezzanine + MySQL

Tags: mysql, cms

So, here is a question:

How to deploy [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/), a Django CMS, locally with MySQL instead of default SQLite?

What is the exact recipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script in one piece is in [->here](https://github.com/ddsherstennikov/docs/blob/master/mezz/install_guide.txt)

**1. Python**

Python is preinstalled in Ubuntu and AFAIK it's vital to some system/desktop-env operations, but just in case:

```
sudo apt-get install python
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

**2. MySQL**

You need to install (a)server, (b)client, (c)dev libs & headers, (d)python adapter

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.5
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

**3. Credentials**

Establish MySQL credentials, tutorial on this is [->here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#After_installing_MySQL), so that you have the following users with corresponding login commands:

- root user

  ```
  mysql -u root -p / password
  ```
- Mezzanine user

  ```
  mysql -u mezz -p / masterkey
  ```

**4. Install Mezzanine**

```
pip install mezzanine
```

**5. Create Project**

```
mezzanine-project myproject
cd myproject
```

**6. Configure db to MySQL**

Use your credentials from step 3.

```
vim local_settings.py
```

That's a Python file. DATABASES variable should be made to be like this (use your credentials at *italicized* places):

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        # Ends with "postgresql_psycopg2", "mysql", "sqlite3" or "oracle".
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        # DB name or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        "NAME": "myproject",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "USER": "mezz",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "PASSWORD": "masterkey",
        # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        "HOST": "",
        # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        "PORT": "",
    }
}
```

**7. Do Mezzanine routines**

Collect static files and templates

```
python manage.py collectstatic  
python manage.py collecttemplates
```

Synchronize with database. This step depends on the Django version, [at the time of writing this, Django 1.7 is still not supported](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine), so use `syncdb`:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

You may also consifer using South migration manager, but know that South project is at it's dusk since Django 1.7 has new migration system.

After syncdb output you'd have a superuser (for entering Mezzanine's admin section). You can create superuser separately after sync:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Run built-in server of Mezzanine (more concretely, it's Django's lightweight server):

```
python manage.py runserver
```

**8. Go**

Point your browser at `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and hopefully you'll see the Mezzanine standard greeting.

**9. Production Deployment**

[->Here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/How%20to%20use%20Mezzanine%20on%20PythonAnywhere) is a good guide, you can use it to create a demo site in production environment (on that particular site it's free with some limits). And [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/UsingMySQL) are their settings for MySQL.

**10. Extras**

- [Official Mezzanine Installation Instructions (for SQLite)](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html#installation)
- [Mezzanine static files explanation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/frequently-asked-questions.html#why-aren-t-my-javascript-and-css-files-showing-up)
- [Mezzanine templates explanation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/frequently-asked-questions.html#templates)
- [More on customizing templates](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1195/)
- [Django Deployment Instructions, part about virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/deploy.html)

**11. 'Revisions'**

Some revisions I gathered on my way:

- South migration manager needs some change in Database section of your settings.py
- Mezzanine and versioning seemed very frustrating to me: it doesn't support django 1.7, and on my hosting provider there was no root access, so I should have installed MySQL-Python ('adapter') through pip. Some versions of adapter-mezzanine-django are incompatible.

For now, I use Mezzanine v3.1.10, Django v1.6.10 and MySQL-Python v1.2.3 and it works. I disabled South backend addon, because it made things for my deployment more complex rather than simpler.

**12. Postscript**

If someone advises me about how to improve this guide, I will do it. j-D

Comment: Thanks for edits. I feel very confused now. j-D (feel free to del this comment, didn't know how to respond elsewhere).

Comment: thx, @karel, all fine. you're the best j-D

Comment: How come we do not need the `manage.py createdb --noinput` step?

Comment: To create a database for the project one can use this command: 
CREATE DATABASE myproject;